# Select count distinct columnname as cnt from tablename

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a table called 'users' which has a column name 'gender' whose values are 'male' and 'female for all affected rows.

I want a `row->count()` of all distinct 'male' values and all distinct 'female' values.

```
$sql = "SELECT gender  FROM users"; 
$namequery = $db->prepare( $sql );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (and this is just general SQL syntax):

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(Name) [Count], 
     gender 
FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT (name) [Name], gender FROM users)
GROUP BY gender
```